# What are the maximum number of Native platforms in android

Tags: android, android-studio-3.4

While releasing an update I came across this[image]

and this is for the previous update I'd released
[image]

Could some please tell me what are the maximum number of native platforms in android or why does this show in this new update and not in the older ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know following are all of Abi's some of them which are deprecated now :

> "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi-v8a", "x86","x86_64", "mips",
>   "mips64"

you can check more details here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits

Comment: Android Plugin for Gradle 3.1.0 and higher no longer generate APKs for the following ABIs by default: mips, mips64, and armeabi. That's because NDK r17 and higher no longer include these ABIs as supported targets.